# date conversion in react-native-library

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have created a react native library. I access the HealthKit features using React Native's NativeModule.
I have an index file as below and a swift file with all the healthkit methods. Interacting with the healthkit methods using NativeModules

The **index.tsx** file of my library:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { MyHealthLibrary } = NativeModules;

export default MyHealthLibrary as any;
```

I install and use this library for my App development.

I want to do the date conversion in the library. I will send Date from my App to this library and the Date needs to be converted to String here in the index.tsx file.

I am very new to this. 
How can i do this???

Comment: Where are you sending the date?

Comment: Sending the date to the swift file in my react-native-library

Comment: Assuming that you want to convert date to string, you can use .toISOString()